CatalogResolver: Cannot resolve the name 'type' to a(n) 'type definition' component
I'm using a CatalogResolver to validate xml against xsd files. This works fine for most cases but now I have a complex xsd with many includes and imports. Unfortunately this does not work. I tried to break down the problem to a very basic example and this is what I ended with:
Validation-Code-Snippet:
    public void validate(Source pXMLInputSource) throws SAXException, IOException {
        if (pXMLInputSource == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("pXMLInputSource darf nicht null sein.");

        SchemaFactory lSchemaFactory = SecureXMLProcessingUtil.getSecureSchemaFactory();

        if (mErrorHandler == null) {  mErrorHandler = new PassThroughErrorHandler(); }
        lSchemaFactory.setErrorHandler(mErrorHandler);

        if (mResolver != null) {
            lSchemaFactory.setResourceResolver(mResolver); // CatalogResolver
        }

        Schema lSchema =  lSchemaFactory.newSchema();

        Validator lValidator = lSchema.newValidator();

        if (mResolver != null) {
            lValidator.setResourceResolver(mResolver); // CatalogResolver
        }
        lValidator.setErrorHandler(mErrorHandler);
        lValidator.validate(pXMLInputSource);
    } 

simpleXSDWithInclude.xsd:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:incl="MyNamespace"
           targetNamespace="MyNamespace">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="simpleIncludedXSD.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="simpleRootElement">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="SimpleElement" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="bla" type="incl:MyComplexType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

simpleIncludedXSD.xsd:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="MyNamespace">
    <xs:element name="simpleIncludedElement">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="MyComplexType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="MySimpleString" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

simpleTest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--XML-Beispieldatei von XMLSpy generiert v2023 rel. 2 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<incl:simpleRootElement xmlns:incl="MyNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="MyNamespace simpleXSDWithInclude.xsd">
    <SimpleElement>String</SimpleElement>
    <bla>
        <MySimpleString>String</MySimpleString>
    </bla>
</incl:simpleRootElement>


testCatalog.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <group prefer="public">

        <public publicId="MyNamespace" uri="../schemas/simpleXSDWithInclude.xsd"/>

    </group>
</catalog>

The xsd-files and the xml-file are valid (tested with Altova-XML-Spy) but validating results in this error:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/.../Classes_Test/.../xml/xmlwrapper/resource/schemas/simpleXSDWithInclude.xsd; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 55; src-resolve: Name 'incl:MyComplexType' kann nicht als 'type definition'-Komponente aufgelöst werden.

Any idea what is wrong and how I can solve this problem with a CatalogResolver?
Changing the xsd-files is not possible as they are provided from an external source.
Any help is really appreciated :).
